# Handling CSS load failure

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been spending some thinking time recently on how to best handle resource failure for a page.

Of course with JavaScript files there isn't much 'clever' stuff that you can do. If you're loading from a CDN we can do something like this (taken from the HTML5 Boilerplate project):

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="local/jquery-1.6.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

However I haven't seen much documented on CSS failure.

If your page is a blog post or something similar then best practice would be to make sure your markup is good, so that the un-formatted version is still a very much readable, if only a little boring, document.

But what if you don't want to fall back to Lynx style? There may be a good reason; for example your application is complicated and is very much dependant on your layout. In which case, showing the page with no stylesheet is probably worse for user experience than not showing it at all.

**Therefore, I wondered if a solution such as this would work - and if any of you are using it (or something similar)?**

1. Add a helper class at the end of your CSS file `#test { line-height: 1; }`
2. Add this JavaScript at the end of your page

---

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.setAttribute('id', 'test');
document.body.appendChild(el);

var o = (el.currentStyle) ? el.currentStyle['line-height'] :

    (window.getComputedStyle) ? document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('line-height') : null;
if (o !== '1px') {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<p>Resources failed to load, a prettier message should go here</p>';
}
```

See this [JS Fiddle for it all together](http://jsfiddle.net/beardtwizzle/qUHz8/).

**Questions are**

1. Thoughts on the above?
2. Are you using something like this?
3. Do you think its a good pattern (note that I'm only advocating this for web apps that are reliant on their styles).

Comment: Not really an answer to the question you asked, so I'll just comment: You don't need to go get the `div` again with `getElementById`, you already have it (in your `t` variable). In fact, you'll find that `el === t` is true.

Comment: Good point! Will amend my post now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule may not take due to user stylesheets or other browser settings overriding the rule you're testing on. `line-height` seems especially vulnerable to this, plus also any rule that takes a length value runs the risk of returning a `computedStyle` in a different unit to the one you expected, making the string comparison fail. (Not to mention the `1`/`1px` confusion in your example.)

In general I think this needs to fail better. If you think styles haven't loaded, add a warning to the page by all means, but don't replace the whole page with an error, making it completely useless to someone who might have been able to at least try to use it. This fragility is bad for accessibility.

Comment: Yes, I can't read. :-) Oh, probably want to put the standards-compliant code as the first branch (`if ('getComputedStyle' in window)`), falling back to `currentStyle` if not present.

Comment: So if I read you correctly this. With some additional tweaking (and of course partial redrawing rather than wiping the whole display) it's a good add to a project?

Comment: Disagree, most sites would be useless without their CSS and having the page replaced with a pretty inline styled error message would be more friendly then a broken looking page of unstyled elements. You should break the CSS down into necessary and optional, and treat each accordingly.